# Angularjs highlight td cell dynamically based on DB value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-class

How to highlight TD cell dynamically based on DB value of weekday and shift number  using below code.

Able to display weekday and Date using function getDates().
  after binding to TD cell as 
 $scope.dates = getDates();

For example if the below function getCurrentShiftDtls returns weekday = fri and shift no = 2 then I want to highlight(change Bg color) of

```
<td colspan="3" id="tdFri"> and <td id="tdFri2">B</td>
```

How can I do this

```
code:
```

```js
function getCurrentShiftDtls(PlId, A_Id) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://xxx/api/Shift/GetShiftDtls',
    params: {
      PlId: PlId,
      A_Id: A_Id
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'dataType': 'json'
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    var ShiftDtls = response.data;
    shiftDay = ShiftDtls[0].WeekDay; // shiftDay = Fri
    shiftNo = ShiftDtls[0].ShiftNo; // shiftNo = 2
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // alert(response);
  });
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <table class="tbWeek">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" id="tdMon">{{dates[0]}}</td> // Mon 3/25
          <td colspan="3" id="tdTue">{{dates[1]}}</td> // Tue 3/26 .. ..
<td colspan="3" id="tdFri" ng-class="{'highlight': shiftDay === 'Fri'} ">{{dates[4]}}</td>
          <td colspan="3" id="tdSun">{{dates[6]}}</td> // Sun 3/31
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="tdMon1">A</td>
          <td id="tdMon2">B</td>
          <td id="tdMon3">C</td>
          ... ...
          <td id="tdSun1">A</td>
          <td id="tdSun2">B</td>
          <td id="tdSun3">C</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

     <style>
    .highlight {
                background: red;
            }
```

Comment: Angularjs and Angular are two different things. Please pick one.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an ID of `tdFri` and `tdFri2`, and you get data back that is `shiftDay = Fri` and `shiftNo = 2`

It seems to me that you just need to combine these and make some strings to select the elements by ID.

```js
var selectors = '#td' + shiftDay + ', #td' + shiftDay + shiftNo;  //'#tdFri, #tdFri2'
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
elements.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.add('highlighted');
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
    background: yellow;
}
```

---

Or perhaps a better more "angularJS" way to do this would be to put those values onto the angular scope and then add a class in the template

```html
<td colspan="3" id="tdFri" ng-class="{'highlight': shiftDay ==='Fri'}">
or maybe
<td colspan="3" id="tdFri" ng-class="{'highlight': shiftDay === date[4]}">
```